# Powershell basics output management

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm asking some help because I'm stuck with my little script.

I try to get a list of users from a specific AD group and to get more information with a loop. Below is the script I have already done but I get errors.  Someone can help me get this working ?

```
$users = get-adgroupmember -identity "Group101" | select SamAccountName
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -properties mail | Select samaccountname,mail
} | Export-CSV user-emails.txt
```

Comment: `but I get errors` ..Can you share them

Comment: $users = get-adgroupmember -identity "Group101" | select SamAccountName -ExpandProperty samaccountname

Comment: Remove `| select SamAccountName` from the `get-adgroupmember` line and fix the typo for `users =` --> `$users =`. Also add switch `-NoTypeInformation` to the Export-Csv cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I followed the instructions of Theo and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) has provided an effective workaround in a comment, but let me explain **the immediate problem with your code**:

`get-adgroupmember -identity "Group101" | select SamAccountName` doesn't store *mere account names* in `$users`, it stores `[pscustomobject]` instances that *have a `.SamAccountName` property* containing the account names.

Such `[pscustomobject]` instances *as a whole* aren't recognized as valid arguments for `Get-ADUser`'s `-Identity` parameter, which is why you got errors.

The **immediate fix** would have been to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) with the `-ExpandProperty` parameter, so as to ensure that only the account names themselves are stored in `$users`:

```sh
# Note the use of -ExpandProperty
$users = get-adgroupmember -identity "Group101" | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -properties mail | Select samaccountname,mail
} | Export-CSV user-emails.txt
```

However, you can **simplify your command**, taking advantage of **pipeline-based parameter binding**:

```sh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group101" | 
  Get-ADUser -Properties mail | 
    Select samaccountname, mail |
      Export-CSV user-emails.txt
```

Note:

- This assumes that the `[ADPrincipal]` instances output by `Get-ADGroupMember` can directly bind to `Get-ADUser`'s `-Identity` parameter via the pipeline, which I cannot personally verify (but which your feedback suggests works).
- As Theo notes, if you're using *Windows PowerShell*, you may want to add `-NoTypeInformation` to your [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) call; also, `-Encoding` allows you to control the output character encoding.